spring security 6 403 error when i call an public endpoint
I'm trying to resolve a problem with Spring Security 6, but I can't. In my SecurityConfig class, I implemented the securityfilter method with a signup endpoint at permitAll to not authenticate, but when I make a post call with /signup, I receive a 403.
How can I solve this problem
My Security Config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
  private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
  private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;


  public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.jwtAuthFilter = jwtAuthFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }


  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
      HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
    return http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(
            session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        //        Set permissions on endpoints
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            auth ->
                auth
                    //            public endpoints
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/signup/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/login/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/authentication-docs/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    //             private endpoints
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login"))
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
        http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
  }
}

My UserDetailsServiceImpl:
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UserRepository repository;

  public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {


    UserEntity userEntity =
        repository
            .findByUsername(email)
            .orElseThrow(
                () ->
                    new NotFoundException(String.format("User does not exist, email: %s", email)));

    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedRoles = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userEntity.getRole().name()));

    return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
        .username(userEntity.getUsername())
        .password(userEntity.getPassword())
        .authorities(grantedRoles)
        .build();
  }
}

My controller :
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/auth", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AuthController {

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  private final UserService userService;

  public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserService userService) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.userService = userService;
  }
  
  @PostMapping("/signup")
  public UserDto signup(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequest requestDto) {
    return userService.signup(requestDto);
  }

  @PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> login(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequest request) {
    try {
      authenticationManager.authenticate(
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
      throw e;
    }

    String token = JwtHelper.generateToken(request.getUsername());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new UserResponse(request.getUsername(), token));
  }
}

And then i call my public endpoint http://localhost:8087/api/auth/signup/ , I 403 Forbidden.

How can i fix this problem please

Please share how do you call the signup endpoint

Hi @CaptainAye this is my postman call

Try calling "http://localhost:8087/api/auth/signup" (without trailing slash). Does it help?

@CaptainAye i try to call with http://localhost:8087/api/auth/signup but i have the same problem

do you get any stacktrace, logs etc.? At the first sight your config looks ok and I wasn't able to reproduce the issue

@obela06 Hit this (http://localhost:8087/api/auth/signup) in Chrome browser and check developer console.. It's possible you're getting multiple 302 redirect or error

/api/auth/signup/** doesn't match /api/auth/signup which your actual URL is or at least it shouldn't match. You should write the URLs as they match your controllers URL another one is that you might be redirected to /error for some reason and as you have .anyRequest().authenticated() that is protected. Another thing is you configured formLogin but that should have a permitAll at the end as well.
